# Salesforce managed package that only redirects

Tags: app-development, appexchange, app

I am totally new to SF so my question might sound weak. I want to publish an app to the appexchange store. The only functionality of this app would be to redirect the user to a configured URL when the app is added by an enterprise admin. What is the easiest way to do that?

Basically all other functionality will be handled by my URL endpoint(authorization/business logic).

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect the user"? You want the user to actually leave the Salesforce environment and go to another webpage?

Comment: Look at Canvas to be able to surface an External Application in Salesforce. Alternatively, you can just use a Webtab or have a Quick Link in the Sidebar.

Comment: @Lex, yes i want to redirect the user to my endpoint when he adds the app

Comment: @techtrekker, How can I register a quick link to any enterprise's salesforce portal when they have not yet added my app?

Comment: If all you need is a redirect URL, the local Salesforce admin can create a link or web tab like @techtrekker says. Why would you need an app for that?

Comment: That is the point of making the app, so the local admin does not have to create a link. This is part of a workflow where I want the admin to add my app which will redirect him

Comment: No work should be done by the local admin. He should only add my app and it should do its work from there onwards

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about "how to publish to the App Exchange", you'll want to take a look at the [App Distribution Wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/App_Distribution) which has links to the many resources available for people who want to develop apps and publish them to the App Exchange.

Comment: My question was to get the easiest method of achieving the redirect functionality and packaging it in the form of an app. It has no other function. Just a one time redirect.

Comment: The links on the page I gave you will tell you how to package your app and take you to the pages where you can learn about the approval process.

Comment: If you want to develop a method for achieving redirect functionality for packaging as **your** App, I suggest you post your coding efforts to date for review by others to see if they can assist you where you're having difficulties with your code.