# How to create an app/package whose sole functionality is to redirect?

Tags: managed-package, oauth, appexchange, remote-access

I want to create an app/package to be published on the appexchange.  The only functionality of that app/package will be to redirect the user to a configured URL in the app. This will happen once enterprise admin adds the app from the appexchange.

The redirect functionality is related to remote access via Oauth2. Once redirected to the URL, the URL endpoint will kick in and do all the further steps.

I do NOT want the admin of the enterprise to make any config e.g creating webtab or a link as a workaround to making some package. This SHOULD be done when the app is added.

In other words, can we make an app that does not contain any tab, but just a URL?

Also, Can we package remote access apps?

Comment: How is this really different from your other question [Salesforce managed package that only redirects](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/salesforce-managed-package-that-only-redirects)  ?

Comment: The answers i was getting were mostly related to publishing the app rather then making the app. So probably people were being misled. I thought of re-asking and deleting the prev one

Comment: You can guide answers by making your question more specific (updates are encouraged) and commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you review [Force.com Platform Fundamentals Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf) which has a complete tutorial on building an App. I think you'll find the answer to what constitutes an App there. To help you get the most benefit from Salesforce StackExchange, you may find it helpful to look at our [FAQ](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/faq) which explains how to post effectively when you visit this site.

I'll add that I also believe you'd have also discovered the answers to your question through the many resources available to developers linked from the Wiki provided to you in the response to your previous post.